При перезапуске телеграм бота кнопки выводятся повторно
from turtle import onclick
import telebot 
from telebot import types #type #ignore
import sqlite3



bot = telebot.TeleBot('7450038879:AAHWaR7eRW16dAp2QR4Z_L7XFJ2OBJOyKto')

markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=False, resize_keyboard=True)
Unumber = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard = True, resize_keyboard=True)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Бот KURILKA приветствует вас! ', reply_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('номер телефона',request_contact=True,)
    Unumber.row(btn3) 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут вы можете ознакомиться с акциями и скидками, а так же принять участие в нашей бонуснуй системе!', reply_markup=Unumber)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number)
    

пробовал очищать очищать клавиатуру перед каждым стартом, отдельной функцией. Все равно, если бот запущен на сервере, то при его удалении и новым стартом в телеграме выводятся по 2 пары одинаковых кнопок.

